# pow(X,Y,Z) <=> Z = X^Y with add

Tags: prolog, addition, pow

Would it be possible to do "pow" with "add" predicate (or just `X is Y + Z` )?
I make this:

```
pow(0,1,1).
pow(_,0,1).
pow(X,Y,Z) :- Y1 is Y - 1, pow(X,Y1,Z1), Z is Z1 * X.
```

But I want also make it with " + " (just for practise) like `3^2 = 3 * 3 = 3 + 3 + 3`

Comment: Well you can write multiplication in terms of addition...

Comment: `pow(X, Y, Z) :- Z is X^Y+0.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the multiplication (`mul/3`) in terms of addition. Like:

```
pow(0,1,1).
pow(_,0,1).
pow(X,Y,Z) :-
    Y > 1,
    Y1 is Y - 1,
    pow(X,Y1,Z1),
    mul(Z1,X,Z). %% originally: Z is Z1 * X.

mul(0,_,0).
mul(I,A,R) :-
    I > 0,
    I1 is I-1,
    mul(I1,A,R1),
    R is R1 + A.
```

Usually a basic exercise is to write *addition*, *multiplication*, and *power* predictates with the *Peano number representation*. In that case addition is written with the successor functor.